# What's the difference between "Richtext" and "HTML text"?

Tags: mockup-tool, evolus-pencil

I'm on Evolus Pencil Project 3.1.0 on Linux 64x.

Both elements seem to be exactly the same?

I thought that "HTML text" could allow you to type directly with HTML tag, contrary to Richtext, but if it's not the case.

(For example, if I type in the HTML text box: 
`look to this <a href="mylink.com">link</a>`, it doesn't appear as a link)

Comment: HTML is an open standard. Rich Text isn't. In fact "Rich Text" is not just one standard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format

Comment: Another resource that could help: http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-html-and-rich-text/

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't tell me what it changes if I choose "HTML text" and not "Richtext" in Evolus Pencil...

Comment: I guess that HTML rendering is not a feature currently supported by this program. This appears to be a product question.

Comment: it IS a product question. I've especially chosen the tags for that.